# Filter out osm data that have been edited after some timestamp

Tags: openstreetmap, filter, osmosis, josm, timestamp

I want to get data after some `timestamp`. I have downloaded the osm file of the area. I went through the osmosis [documentation](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis) but could not find a way to filter it by time.

The result should be same as when we use the `timestamp:sometime` in JOSM.

1. I could use JOSM but copy pasting in new layer removes old id, user info and gives new ids, also
2. i could use the overpass but the area is large and overpass timed out many times
3. i have also tried [osmfilter](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmfilter) but it can't filter by time

Comment: Duplicated question: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/28117/filter-out-data-that-have-been-edited-after-some-timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JOSM, select things you don't need and then purge(same as delete but it removes the records as well)

Answer (score 0):

So you refer to the timestamp that a osm object had been touched (or created)?

I would recommend to **work offline** and get an appropriate Planet extract. Sadly AFAIK there is no tool that works with OSM that way, as they use a slightly different method for replication (based on changesets and version numbering).
So you need to do it manually:

- [download .pbf extract](http://planet.osm.org/) that you need
- cut it using [osmosis](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis) till it fits your area and export it as .XML
- create **custom script** that filters [OSM XML](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/XML) basing on the timestamp="" XML attribute.

Due to the amount of data, you need to use a SAX XML parser instead of DOM. You might also consider, that to reconstruct a datasnapshot, nodes can be changed independently to ways and both of them interdependently to relations.

I don't know your exact usecase, but maybe the [history planet](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/History_Planet) is a better way to get your results. This depends on the size of your area and what you like to get. If you just like to view the date of your area, you might use [OSMatrix](http://osmatrix.uni-hd.de/) and to monitor, you might have a look at this tools:
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Quality_Assurance#Monitoring_Tools

Comment: As you stated, the first two steps have been already done. Looks like i will have to write a custom script. Thank you.